# Problem with local file server connection dialogue

Tags: network, mac-mini, osx-server

I am running a Mac Pro (mid 2012) and a Mac mini file server. The Mac Pro is running Mojave and the mac mini is running El Capitan. I connect to the Mac mini server using SMB (AFP doesn't work for some reason... even though it is enabled in the sharing panel on the Mac mini).

My problem is that after connecting to the Mac mini, I get a dialogue on the Mac Pro that looks like this:

[image: Error message]

I dismiss this dialogue, and it immediately comes back. I dismiss it again and it comes back.

I am wondering how to keep this dialogue from appearing? Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does "server.local" resolve to an IP? Go to the terminal and enter `nslookup server.local` to check,

Comment: @not2savvy looks like it does not. The results of that terminal command is:
** server can't find server.local: NXDOMAIN
It's odd though because in the file sharing on the Mac Mini, it says it can be at afp://192.xxx.x.xx

Comment: What‘s the DNS configured in your Mac Pro‘s network settings? Can you post the full output of nslookup?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not very good in Terminal. When I do jsut "nslookup" it doesn't do anything? When I did "nslookup server.local" this was the full results:

Server:  192.168.1.1
Address: 192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find nslookup: NXDOMAIN

Comment: That‘s fine. So 192.168.1.1 is your DNS server which is probably your router, right? Does your router‘s UI show a list if connected devices? Is one of them called ‚server‘? Is ‚server‘ actually the network name of your Mac Mini?

Comment: Yes, I see a device called "SERVER" in my router app. It has a IP address and a MAC address listed. Do you need those settings?

Comment: No, I don‘t. It should work then, I guess. Can you try to connect via SMB to the IP address displayed there instead of ‚server.local‘. Does it work?

Comment: Well, I can connect to it via SMB just fine. The server is mounted on the Mac Pro desktop now. It's this pesky dialogue box I can't rid of that is driving me nuts.

Comment: Oh so you can connect despite this error message?

Comment: Yes, via SMB. AFP does not work for some reason. After I connect, I get the error dialogue box that was in my original post.

Comment: Maybe the root problem is AFP not working. Not sure why though. You aren’t running LittleSnitch or any virus stuff, are you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108549/discussion-between-colin-and-not2savvy).